# How to save faceted plot on a custom grid (as in geofacet) without printing empty facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the example from the [`geofacet` tutorial](https://ryanhafen.com/blog/geofacet/).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(geofacet)

ggplot(state_ranks, aes(variable, rank, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_geo(~ state, grid = "us_state_grid2")
```

The output in the RStudio plot viewer looks fine.[image]

But when saved using `ggsave` it prints all the empty facets.

```
ggsave("~/desktop/StateFacets.png")
```

[image]

How can I save this plot so that the empty facets aren't rendered?

Comment: Does it need to be a png? Maybe try other formats e.g. pdf - https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html. No idea if it will work but worth trying if not stuck to a specific format

Comment: I've tried both pdf and png with the same result

Comment: Hmm, when I assign a name to the plot and save that I don't see the issue.  So if I named the plot `p1`, saving with `ggsave("StateFacets.png", plot = p1)` looks fine for me.  I can reproduce the extra grids when saving the "last plot" in `ggsave()` as you are.

Comment: Oh wow, @aosmith. That solves it. Silly not to try that on my part. If you leave that response as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem when using the default `plot = last_plot()` like you are in `ggsave()`.

It looks like a work-around is to assign the plot a name and use that as the `plot` when saving.  Then the extra facets aren't saved.

```
p1 = ggplot(state_ranks, aes(variable, rank, fill = variable)) +
     geom_col() +
     coord_flip() +
     theme_bw() +
     facet_geo(~ state, grid = "us_state_grid2")

ggsave("~/desktop/StateFacets.png", plot = p1)
```